# Odd Count of icons along with GapLocation.center cause render issue

Tags: flutter

I want to make bottom navigator with AnimatedBottomNavigationBar package, but when I do "gapLocation: GapLocation.end" it gives an error.

```
 class _marketViewPageState extends State<marketViewPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text(" Page "),
        ),
        floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
          child: const Icon(Icons.add),
          onPressed: () {},
        ),
        floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.endDocked,
        bottomNavigationBar: AnimatedBottomNavigationBar(
          activeColor: Colors.red,
          height: Get.height /
              12, 
          backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
          notchSmoothness: NotchSmoothness.defaultEdge,
          leftCornerRadius: 15,
          gapLocation: GapLocation.end,
          icons: [
            Icons.home,
            Icons.add_shopping_cart_outlined,
            Icons.history_rounded,
            Icons.star,
            Icons.circle
          ],

          activeIndex: 1,
          onTap: (int) {
            print(int);
          },
          //other params
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Screen

[image]

Error

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The error says that you have odd count of icons. Which mean the total icons is 5 so docking it in the center is not possible. Consider adding one more icon to the item or remove an icon and it should work as expected. Also to center the floating action button use

```dart
floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerDocked,
```

Or if you wish to make it floating try

```dart
floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerFloat,
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change `floatingActionButtonLocation`to:

```
floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerFloat,
```

Comment: kindly, avoid answering duplicate questions, instead provide link to the already answered question !!!

Comment: @OMiShah Sometimes answering is faster than finding duplicates, [What to do with answer on duplicate question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/352194/10157127)

Comment: @YeasinSheikh I hope you read what does it says xD